# I was getting errors like Task :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets FAILED , Task :app:packageRelease FAILED these when i try to run android emulator

Tags: android, react-native

[image: not reloading the build file]There are some solutions in the StackOverflow to do some commands but I need to know why these errors are occuring and how to avoid these errors briefly  [image: relase mode]

Comment: How exactly do you expect someone to help you, having provided so little details?

Comment: I made my app ready for release mode removed the debug configs in build.gradle file everything is working fine, using npx react-native run-android --variant=release to launch the emulator. then after changing the code and then again running the above command i was getting these errors. idont know the reasons there is no errors in the code because i was just a text. i dont get these errors when i am in debug mode even the metro is not working it cannot reload the live changes when i am changing the code

Comment: it says no emulator is available all these errors have some solutions but i need what is causing these errors. i added two images above hope u can understand the situation

Comment: I don't see the error that you have described in the question, I see that there is a problem with a bundler, which I think you can try to restart to see if the error goes away. Does the app work fine not in a release mode? (just `react-native run-android`)

Comment: In debug mode if i made a change then the metro will automatically reloads the app and display the results in emulators but here in release mode the metro is not even recognising the emulator. When i need to reload the app i have to run the emulator command again.the errors i have mentioned in the question are occurring without my knowledge and then if run build command then it works fine. So i need to learn the reason for occurrence of the error

Comment: Having looked at it again, the problem is that you have not signed your app. You have to substitute all of the `MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE` by your own variables, otherwise android can't sign your release and it doesn't work. Follow this guide to do that https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android